# How do I code a property with sub-properties?

Tags: delphi

For instance, like Font.  Can anyone give a very simple example? Maybe just a property with two sub-properties

---

Edit:  I mean that when I look at Font in the object inspector it has a little plus sign which I can click to set font name "times new roman", font size "10", etc. Sorrry if I use the wrong terms, that is what I menat by "sub-properties".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you have to do is create a new published property that points to an type that has published properties.

check this code

```
  type
    TCustomType = class(TPersistent) //this type has 3 published properties
    private
      FColor : TColor;
      FHeight: Integer;
      FWidth : Integer;
    public
      procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    published
      property Color: TColor read FColor write FColor;
      property Height: Integer read FHeight write FHeight;
      property Width : Integer read FWidth write FWidth;
    end;

    TMyControl = class(TWinControl) 
    private
      FMyProp : TCustomType;
      FColor1 : TColor;
      FColor2 : TColor;
      procedure SetMyProp(AValue: TCustomType);
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
    published
      property MyProp : TCustomType read FMyProp write SetMyProp; //now this property has 3 "sub-properties" (this term does not exist in delphi)
      property Color1 : TColor read FColor1 write FColor1;
      property Color2 : TColor read FColor2 write FColor2;
    end;

  procedure TCustomType.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
  var
    Src: TCustomType;
  begin
    if Source is TCustomType then
    begin
      Src := TCustomType(Source);
      FColor := Src.Color;
      Height := Src.Height;
      FWidth := Src.Width;
    end else
      inherited;
  end;

  constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
    inherited;
    FMyProp := TCustomType.Create;
  end;

  destructor TMyControl.Destroy;
  begin
    FMyProp.Free;
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TMyControl.SetMyProp(AValue: TCustomType);
  begin
    FMyProp.Assign(AValue);
  end;
```

Comment: The setter for the TMyControl.MyProp property should not be writing to FMyProp directly. That will leak the original FMyProp object and take ownership of the caller's object.  Instead, it needs to use a setter method that calls FMyProp.Assign(), and then TCustomType needs to implement Assign().

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, sub-properties?  There is no such thing in Delphi.

Perhaps you mean object composition where an object contains a reference to another object, for example -

```
interface

type
TObj1 = class
private
  FFont: TFont;  
  property Font: TFont read FFont;
end;

...

implementation

var
  MyObj: TObj1;
begin
  MyObj1 := TObj1.Create;
  MyObj1.Font.Name := 'Arial';
```

Comment: (+1 thanks for replying) I mean that when I look at Font in the object inspector it has a littl eplus sign which I can click to set fonat name "times new roman", font size "10", etc.  Sorrry if I use the wrong terms, that is what I menat by "sub-properties".