# How do I code a property with sub-properties? (redux)

Tags: delphi

I am sure that I got a good answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725037/how-do-i-code-a-property-with-sub-properties) because I have previously had a great deal of help on other questions from the guys who posted there.

But I am obviously doing something wrong, because when I copy the example code what the object inspector shows me for the MyProp property is a single text input field. I was expecting to see something that looks like the Font property, with Pitch, font family, etc i.e I expect to see a tree structure but I don't see the Color, Height or Width properties of the MyProp property.

Any ideas? Again, I copied that code exactly.

---

Edit: I forgot to mention (in this question) that I am using TMS scripter pro, which allows users to design forms at run time and provides its own object inspector, but that is probably derived from standard Delphi stuff, I guess.

Anyway, it appears that I am too dumb to code Delphi as I simply can't get this to work.

---

Edit: TMS assure me that if the class with "sub-properties) is descended from TPresistent then it will appear in the object inspector with sub-properties, just like Font, Anchors, etc

When I use this code, the "Warning" property appears as a text field in the object inspector and has no sub-properties

```
unit IntegerEditBox;
  // An edit box which only accepts integer values and warns if the value is not in a certain range

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls,
  EditBox_BaseClass;

type

  TWarning = Class(TPersistent)
    private
      FWarningBelowValue   : Integer;
      FWarningAboveValue   : Integer;
      FWarningEmailTo : String;
      FWarningSmsTo   : String;
    published
      property WarningBelowValue   : Integer read FWarningBelowValue   write FWarningBelowValue;
      property WarningAboveValue   : Integer read FWarningAboveValue   write FWarningAboveValue;
      property WarningEmailTo      : String  read FWarningEmailTo      write FWarningEmailTo;
      property WarningSmsTo        : string  read FWarningSmsTo        write FWarningSmsTo;
  end;


  TIntegerEditBox = class(TEditBox_BaseClass)
    private
      FWarning : TWarning;
      procedure WriteValue(const newValue : Integer);


    protected
      // The new property which w/e introduce in this class
      FValue : Integer;   

    public { Public declarations }
      Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;   // This constructor uses defaults
      property Text;

    published  { Published declarations - available in the Object Inspector at design-time }
      property Hint;

      // Now our own properties, which we are adding in this class
      property Value : Integer read FValue write WriteValue;
      property Warning  : TWarning read FWarning write FWarning ;
  end;  // of class TIntegerEditBox()

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Dialogs;

  procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('Standard', [TIntegerEditBox]);
  end;

  Constructor TIntegerEditBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
    inherited;  // Call the parent Create method
    Hint := 'Only accepts a number|Only accepts a number'; // Tooltip | status bar text
    Mandatory := True;
    Value := 0;
    Text := IntToStr(Value);
  end;

  procedure TIntegerEditBox.WriteValue(const newValue : Integer);
  begin
    Text := IntToStr(newValue);
  end;

end.
```

Comment: The code in the answer you accepted has at least one problem - see Remy Lebeau's comment to the accepted answer for details.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Yes, I will implement that - but I don't see that it should prevent properties from appearing in the object inspector.

Comment: Read [this article](http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc083101e.htm) it explains clearly about creating sub properties.

Comment: The "accepted answer" code in the other discussion only showed declarations, it did not show any actual implementation code, so it is quite possible that you missed important steps.  I have edited the earlier code to show the implementation now.

Comment: +1 I totally agree. That was very bad form of me. My only excuses were that I had a business trip which prevented me from trying it it and that both @RRUZ @Remy who added a few comments have never steered me wrong - just look at their reps.   Unfortunately, SO almost forces you to accept something, just anything; there is no option to say "I didn't get a satisfactory answer", so sometimes I just give it to the guy who put in the most effort. What else to do?

Comment: @Mawg: You have the option to leave the question without an accepted answer for a while.  Is the case with the unique question I posted until now, I got 1 very good answer, but it isn't perfect, and it is not marked as accepted yet.  I want to get the correct one, and I'm willing to cooperate to reach it right.

Comment: Mawg, the code you added when you opened the bounty does not follow the advice that I wrote in my answer. The way to say that an answer is not satisfactory is to comment on the answer and *say* that it's not satisfactory. When you do that, remember to give details about *how* it falls short of your expectations.

Comment: This question asks what's wrong with the code from the previous question. The previous question has an accepted answer, suggesting that there is *nothing* wrong with it now. What further answer do you expect to get for *this* question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3725203/revisions) of [the demo code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725037/how-do-i-code-a-property-with-sub-properties/3725203#3725203) neglected to create an instance of the property object.

```
constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent)
begin
  inherited;
  FMyProp := TCustomType.Create;
end;
```

Don't forget to free it in the destructor.

Remy's comment on that answer points out that the property needs to be assigned differently. The property's `write` accessor shouldn't write directly to the field. Instead, it should have a setter method that works like this:

```
procedure TMyControl.SetMyProp(const Value: TCustomType);
begin
  FMyProp.Assign(Value);
end;
```

That also highlights the requirement that the property class's `Assign` method be implemented, or else you'll get strange error messages like "Cannot assign a TCustomType to a TCustomType." A simple implementation could go like this:

```
procedure TCustomType.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TCustomType then begin
    Color := TCustomType(Source).Color;
    Height := TCustomType(Source).Height;
    Width := TCustomType(Source).Width;
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: These details have been added to the code in the other discussion now.