# How to de-serialize sub-property in delphi?

Tags: delphi, serialization

Since two days ago I started making my own simple classes from scratch, descended from `TObject`, nothing fancy. I also needed to write/read them to/from files, so after some searching, because I haven't yet learned all the ins and outs of serialization and don't fully get them, I borrowed serialization methods from [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/reader-writer.htm). It worked fine as I was testing it. Then I added another class as a property (that's what I'm referring to when I say sup-property: properties of a class that's a property in my class... that's confusing, it needs a proper name), following the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725037/how-do-i-code-a-property-with-sub-properties) SO question on how to actually do that. Now writing to file doesn't seem to raise any errors, then again I'm not sure the sub-properties are written properly or it's just garbage. Reading it back however does cause the

> Exception class EPropertyConvertError with message 'Invalid property type: TSomething'

Since I'm just learning this, I'm not sure what is wrong. I do have a few wild guesses, one of which would be that the `TSomething = Class` maybe has to have it's own serialization methods? In that case how would that even work (cause even I don't believe this assumption)? Another would be that the code I borrowed from *delphi.about.com* can't handle these type of properties? And if so, how could I improve it? And if none of my guesses are correct, how would one make this work? (And I'm using DelphiXE2.)

Code as per request:

```
TSomething = Class
protected
  fNumber: integer;
  fLine: string;
public
  procedure Assign(Source: TObject);
published
  property Number: integer read fNumber write fNumber;
  property Line: string read fLine write fLine;
End;

TOther = Class
public
  procedure LoadFromStream(const Stream: TMemoryStream);
  procedure SaveToStream(const Stream: TMemoryStream);
  constructor Create; virtual;
  destructor Destroy; override;
protected
  fSomething: TSomething;
  procedure SetfSmth(AValue: TSomething);
published
  property Something: TSomething read fSomething write SetfSomething;
end;
```

The implementation for the methods has been borrowed from the two links that have been provided above, I see no need to retype that, unless asked for.

Comment: Is this into the dfm file, or you after something outside of Delphi's standard form persistence mechanism? Hard to help you without somne code as . The interface of TSomething would do, and why did you start with TObject and not TPersistent?

Comment: Is this some sort of challenge where we are meant to guess what your code looks like?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, TSomething has just two fields, one string one integer for testing purposes, and it just seemed simpler to make it a TObject and build it from the ground up. I suppose changing it is easy enough. And this is only my third day playing around with classes, so I just don't know any better

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I assumed this would be a general enough question, subproperty example that comes to mind from existing components would be, oh I don't know, `TFont` in `TButton` for example... Aight I'm adding code.

Comment: In your serialization routines, you have to handle the `tkClass` TTypeKind.

Comment: @LURD, I think I undersnad now, so when it checks for property type, if it's a `tkClass` I should handle that, what would be the best way to do that? call serialization methods for that class? That seems tricky to do... serialization within serialization?

Comment: Call `LoadFromStream/SaveToStream` methods declared in TSomething.

Comment: @LURD, yes, that is exactly what I was thinking, I'll give that a try, even though I'm not sure how that will work within a serialization method (or how both streams are going to be put together, unless that is something I have to take care of myself as well... talking to myself helps), thanks for the input.

Comment: @Raith TPersistent is the ancestor you should use to take part in streaming, it was designed so you could use it for this stuff. If you don't/can't use it you have to reinvent a lot of wheels and tell the IDE all about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serialize TSomething, it must be a sub-component. To do that you have to change one thing: don't derivate the two classes from TObject but rather from TComponent. Then in the TSomething constructor you call

```
Self.SetSubComponent(True);
```

FInally, as your class is a TComponent you won't need anymore the stuffs grabed from *delphi.about* because a TComponent can be directly serialized in a TStream by using **WriteComponent** / **ReadComponent**

You'll see that the process is easyer when choosing the right descendant. Here the choice is logic: if you want to serialize then use TComponent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow up on your idea of giving the TSomething class serialization methods of it's own.

Here's an example, using XML for serialization:

```
TSomething = class(TPersistent)
protected
  FNumber: Integer;
  FLine: String;
public
  procedure WriteToXmlNode(XmlNode: IXmlNode);
  procedure ReadFromXmlNode(XmlNode: IXmlNode);
published
  property Number: Integer read FNumber write FNumber;
  property Line: String read FLine write FLine;
end;

TOther = class(TPersistent)
protected
  FSomething: TSomething;
public
  procedure WriteToXmlNode(XmlNode: IXmlNode);
  procedure ReadFromXmlNode(XmlNode: IXmlNode);
published
  property Something: TSomething read FSomething write FSomething;
end;
```

In other words, letting each of the classes know how to serialize themselves to XML.

The write method of TOther will then look like this:

```
procedure TOther.WriteToXmlNode(XmlNode: IXmlNode)
var
  ChildNode: IXmlNode;
begin
  // Write something
  ChildNode := XmlNode.AddChild('Something');
  Something.WriteToXmlNode(ChildNode);       
end;
```

And the read method will look like this:

```
procedure TOther.ReadFromXmlNode(XmlNode: IXmlNode)
var
  ChildNode: IXmlNode;
begin
  // Read
  ChildNode := XmlNode.ChildNodes.First;
  while Assigned(ChildNode) do
  begin
    // Read something
    if ChildNode.NodeName = 'Something' then
      Something.ReadFromXmlNode(ChildNode);

    // Next child node
    ChildNode := ChildNode.NextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

That's the general gist of it.

I think you'll be using a similar approach in your example, even if you do not choose to serialize to XML.

**Edit**:
It was a bit unclear what you wanted in your question. If you're writing components, and you want the properties of the components to be properly serialized when you work with them at design time, this is not the way to go. The method I describe is for serializing arbitrary objects during runtime.

Comment: this is all fine and dandy but i think that following Tony Hopkinons's suggestion, I might sa aswell not reinvent a weel and use `TPersistent ` forj all my serialization needs. As I said, because I don't know any better I started from `TObject`, but since something other might have that, I might as well use the framework that already exists. The question that I'm asking is as much about improving what I have written (BORROWED) as it is about alternative and better solutions to my issue.

Comment: @Raith Yes, you can proceed in the direction that you're going, and use Delphi's TWriter and TReader classes for serialization. If you do that, you need to handle the property type tkClass, as someone else suggested. Personally I prefer to reinvent the wheel in cases like this, for portability reasons.